# How to create classes to 1 name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im creating some tasks for my game like collect coins or set new record, and idk how to select task in my method right;

Im trying to random select the type of quest, and work with instance of that class but i cant assign it to 1 name "quest" to work with;

```
public class Quests : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text taskText;

    private void Start()
    {
        SelectQuest();
        taskText.text = quest.discription; //doesnt exist
    }

    public void SelectQuest()
    {
        int random = Random.Range(0, 3);
        switch (random)
        {
            case 0:
                Quest quest = new Quest("Set new record to reward");
                break;
            case 1:
                Quest quest = new Quest(1000, "Collect 1000 coins to reward");
                break; //quest cannot be assign because it used on case 0
            case 2:
                Quest quest = new Quest(5000, "Get 5000 score to reward");
                break; //quest cannot be assign because it used on case 0
        }
    }

}

public class Quest
{
    public string Discription;
    public bool isDone = false;
    public int Target;

    public Quest(int target, string discription)
    {
        Target = target;
        Discription = discription;
    }

    public Quest(string discription)
    {
        Discription = discription;
    }

    public bool CheckForComplete(int target)
    {
        if (Target >= target)
            isDone = true;
        return isDone;
    }
}
```

so what i need - how to do it right - i need to work with only 1 type of task named quest, but i cant choose 1 of 3 types for that quest. cant imagine how to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too sure what you are asking for. But I am making an attempt to clean up your code, which may help.

```
public class Quests : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text taskText;

    private void Start()
    {
        var quest = SelectQuest();
        taskText.text = quest?.discription; 
    }

    public Quest SelectQuest()
    {
        int random = Random.Range(0, 3);
        switch (random)
        {
            case 0:
                return new Quest("Set new record to reward");   
            case 1:
                return new Quest(1000, "Collect 1000 coins to reward");
            case 2:
                return new Quest(5000, "Get 5000 score to reward");
            default:
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I though about  return quest; but was doing that wrong. How i know more about classes. Thanks you

Comment: There is not point to have `break;` after return. Also, `SelectQuest()` is invalid as not all paths return a value.

Answer (score 3):

In all honesty, your question hasn't made much sense to me - thought reading through the code I can only assume you're referencing to the switch.

For your switch, you can create the variable `Quest` before setting its value instantly, try the following:

```
    Quest quest;
    switch (random)
    {
        case 0:
            quest = new Quest("Set new record to reward");
            break;
        case 1:
            quest = new Quest(1000, "Collect 1000 coins to reward");
            break; //quest cannot be assign because it used on case 0
        case 2:
            quest = new Quest(5000, "Get 5000 score to reward");
            break; //quest cannot be assign because it used on case 0
    }
```

Also

```
taskText.text = quest.Discription; //doesnt exist
```

should be changed to

```
taskText.text = quest.Discription; //does exist
```

to get the correct reference.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return `Quest` from `SelectQuest()` method:

```
public class Quests : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text taskText;

    private void Start()
    {
        var quest = SelectQuest();
        taskText.text = quest.discription;
    }

    public Quest SelectQuest()
    {
        int random = Random.Range(0, 3);
        switch (random)
        {
            case 0: return new Quest("Set new record to reward");
            case 1: return  new Quest(1000, "Collect 1000 coins to reward");
            case 2: return new Quest(5000, "Get 5000 score to reward");
            default: throw new Exception("Can not select quest");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you are just instantiating the class, you are not setting it into a private prop or sending back as a return value. In the code below the quest instance is returned from the SelectQuest function so you can work with it in the Start function.

```
public class Quests : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text taskText;

    private void Start()
    {
        Quest quest = SelectQuest();
        taskText.text = quest.discription;
    }

    public Quest SelectQuest()
    {
        int random = Random.Range(0, 3);
        switch (random)
        {
            case 0:
                return new Quest("Set new record to reward");
            case 1:
                return new Quest(1000, "Collect 1000 coins to reward");
            case 2:
                return new Quest(5000, "Get 5000 score to reward");
        }
    }

}

public class Quest
{
    public string Discription;
    public bool isDone = false;
    public int Target;

    public Quest(int target, string discription)
    {
        Target = target;
        Discription = discription;
    }

    public Quest(string discription)
    {
        Discription = discription;
    }

    public bool CheckForComplete(int target)
    {
        if (Target >= target)
            isDone = true;
        return isDone;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear, but If I understand what you are looking for.. I think you just need to hold a public `Quest` field/property in your class.

```
public class Quests : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text taskText;
    public Quest SelectedQuest { get; private set; } 

    private void Start()
    {
        SelectedQuest = SelectQuest();
        taskText.text = SelecedQuest?.discription; //doesnt exist
    }

    public void SelectQuest()
    {
        Quest retVal = null;
        int random = Random.Range(0, 3);
        switch (random)
        {
            case 0:
                retVal = new Quest("Set new record to reward");
                break;
            case 1:
                retVal = new Quest(1000, "Collect 1000 coins to reward");
                break; //quest cannot be assign because it used on case 0
            case 2:
                retVal = new Quest(5000, "Get 5000 score to reward");
                break; //quest cannot be assign because it used on case 0
            default:
                break;
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```